# sql server CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to restore a database, and I got the error saying :Error occurred in  Page( 0 0 ).

When I googled this out, the suggestion was to set the option 'CONTINUE after ERROR' to true.
I am not sure how to set this option to true?

What I am doing is  - Right click Database, select restore Database, and selecting the backup file.

Somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

When the first page is corrupt, there is no way to restore the backup. My guess is that this file is not even a backup file.

Comment: it is a back up file. is there a way to set continue after error?

Comment: It will not help because the first page in your file is destroyed. It cannot be restored even with "CONTINUE_after_ERROR". I suggest you Google for "sql server restore CONTINUE_after_ERROR" to find the syntax you arel ooking for (will not work, sorry).